# AngularJS / Javascript - Solution to mask password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passwords, masking

Please let me know how to mask characters such as password in Textbox in Desktop browsers like in phones/handheld devices.

Eg:
Last typing character should be visible for few second for the user and it should mask back to "*".
Password : *************w

I'm using angularJS framework for my web application, Can anyone suggest third party plugin or solution to this feature in angularJS/javascript?

Comment: Did you try input type=password?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="pass" type="password">
```

Comment: Type="password" will always mask the characters all the time (any desktop browsers). The feature is available only on phone or hand held devices. I want a solution for desktop browsers.

Comment: Some thing like this... [link](http://codepen.io/Shajith/pen/xEVjoX) but would like to know any angaularJS plugins available...

Comment: https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1438849509woolies-1-w800.gif

Comment: Do you want to mask only in mobile devices? If yes, you can use twitter bootstrap or css3 for identify the size of screen and show differents inputs.

Comment: No, I want the phone or handheld feature in desktop version. Sample : https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1438849509woolies-1-w800.gif